# Handle Django server errors (5XX) in production to prevent showing sensitve information

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing an API using Django Rest Framework. In the codes, there might be a lot of exceptional situations that we may not think of and cause 5XX errors. One approach to handle these errors is to put a try-exception in the whole function (Or places you guess an unknown error might occur). I want to show the details of the error in the API response (Not just in the logging server) when the debug mode is on in Django. Also, I want to hide these details in production mode (when debug is false) and just pass the error code with no body when the error is 5XX.

Is there any official (and efficient) way to do that? I was thinking of creating a middleware to handle that, but in this case, I should check all responses before passing the response to the user, and this is not efficient at all. I thought there might be a built-in function to handle this stuff, and I can override that to hide the body of the 5XX errors.

Update 1:
For example, I'm using this code in my view:

```
try: # Check if the code is valid
    # Some code which results in Exception
except Exception as e: # noqa
    return Response(str(e), status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

I'm getting the same error when the `DEBUG=False` and `DEBUG=True`. In my case, the error is:

```
"Cannot resolve keyword 'keyword' into field. Choices are: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4"
```

And this response exposes some sensitive fields in the frontend. It seems the `DEBUG=False` will only work for the Django errors, not the errors you are generating (Which totally makes sense because I'm explicitly returning the error in the response).

It seems the `DEBUG=False` works on just the exception trace screen not manually generated 5XX errors.

Comment: You already answered your question. Setting `DEBUG = False` in settings.py will not expose any error information.

Comment: Have you seen "[How to manage error reporting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter.get_traceback_html)" and "[Configuring logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging)"

Comment: @NKSM about the logger, I have mentioned in the question that I need to show the error in detail to the front end in the response. So, the logging system won't work here.
Also, about the error reporting, this is overriding Django's unhandled exception. In my case, I'm handling the exceptions by myself via Django Rest Framework and passing a simple response. In my case, I want to hide the body of the API response when the error code is 5XX.

Comment: Generally, an exception like this means you have an error in your code that you should fix at its source.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Exactly, in my case, I know there is an error by using an Exception, but I don't know the exact result. If I find a safe way to show that, it will decrease the debugging time a lot. I don't need to explore the logs and test locally.

Comment: @Leo, You can stil use [`Custom error reports`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports) or REST_FRAMEWORK has also [**Custom exception handling**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling). It seems that the last one is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Leo It sounds like you need to configure a logging tool, such as Sentry, Firebase, or similar, to report these errors to you rather than doing this manually yourself.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the additional information, you just need to add an `if` statement to decide what to put in the response body. This is what Django already does by default. Alternatively, just let Django do this for you and remove the `try...except`.

Original Answer:

> I want to show the details of the error in the API response (Not just in the logging server) when the debug mode is on in Django. Also, I want to hide these details in production mode (when debug is false) and just pass the error code with no body when the error is 5XX.

You already answered your question. Setting `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` will give an HTML response with the stack trace and other debugging information. Setting `DEBUG = False`, turns off this debugging information and does exactly as you say.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it wasn't my case. I have updated my question and added more details. I was not referring to Django's error trace screen. I have mentioned I have handled the error in a specific way, but I don't want the response to have a body if it is not the debug mode.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for the additional information. I think you can just add an `if` to decide whether to add the error in the body or not.

Comment: Writing the if in all of the views doesn't make sense since it is a repeated task. I was looking to find a better way to handle this error than writing a custom middleware to handle all of the responses and doing and if the condition on all of them.

Comment: why not just wrap the if settings.DEBUG logic in a function that you can reuse like api_error(debug_message, public_message)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the try/except Django should just throw an error as normal - this will display details if settings.DEBUG, otherwise it will show an error template which you can customize to meet your needs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: Yes, I think this could be a good solution, and I need quit to customize the exception and let Django do that for me.